# bash - Moving all files which names end on one of given substrings

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have file with names. My task is to move to another folder all files which names end on name from given file.

```
mapfile -t names< lists.txt
for element in "${names[@]}"; 
do
mask="*"$element
echo $mask
find source -type f -name "$mask" -exec mv -t target {} +
done
```

This is my code, but it doesn't work. Please, explain me how to fix it. It this problem of Cygwin emulator?

Comment: What happens? What is the error?

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work?_

Comment: Files don't move to target folder. Have I worked with mask variable correctly?

Comment: We need more information… because your code runs fine for me.

Comment: What do they do? Are there errors? Help us diagnose. Also, consider xargs. That's a fairly complex script for what sounds like an easy task...

Comment: I  use cygwin emulator

Comment: @PaulHicks: how would `xargs` solve anything? (it would actually _break_ things). OP wrote the script in a rather good style, and that's rare! please dont suggest OP to break their script.

Comment: Cygwin? good luck… and specify that in your question.

Comment: I haven't got a way to try anything, no computer here, but it seems like this could be done with a single pipe and xargs. No script required. But you're right, since I am not in a position to be more specific, I shouldn't have mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the `mv -t` option that you are using here, but I would suggest rewording the `find` command as below:

```
find source -type f -name "$mask" -exec **mv '{}' target \;**
```